# OpenGL Red Book example 1-1 error LNK2019; Problems with GLUT and GLEW, as well as many default libs

Tags: c++, opengl, lnk2019

I got the Red book to expand my currently small knowledge on OpenGL, but the first tutorial is giving me nightmarish problems. You've seen a few of these, I know, but I've got LoadShaders.cpp pointed to and /NODEFAULTLIB set to yes in the project settings, and it has all come down to this last bunch of errors, all or most LNK2019's.

http://pastebin.com/2tTUtiUc Is where you can see the errors. I don't know if I should paste the code here, as you may have already seen it.

One more thing, I tried what the other posters said resolved it for them, but it doesn't resolve it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is wierd to me, but pointing the linker to glew32.lib and freeglut.lib and disabling libcmtd.lib seemed to fix the problem. After that, I can build it with no problem. So, just to repeat, Additional dependencies is set to **only** glew32.lib and freeglut.lib, and ignore default libraries is set to no, and ignore libcmtd.lib.

Comment: I can't accept the answer until tomorrow, so this question will still be open. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should post less complain and more details, so others can do more to help. LNK2019 usually means you are having problem with the linking phase. problems might be:

1. did you put the .lib file under link path? can linkers find them?
2. linking parameter details , could it be related with:

> one of the third-party libraries was not set to /MT in release (but it was /MTd in debug) - changing that flag made it all work.
>   
>   lastly, working directly from working examples instead of set them up all yourselves.

start from [Working Excample](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/), get code directly there.

Comment: So, I should add the folders where I put the .libs to the project through the debugging project properties tab? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: maybe a bit research on how to add libs in c++

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that I should rebuild the .libs for GLEW and FreeGLUT to be set to /MT and MTd for debugging and release purposes.

Comment: Also, I have pinpointed the problematic code, it's in LoadShaders.cpp, and it's interfering with libcmtd.lib. That's what VS pointed me to and I disabled just that library, which let the program compile correctly.